# How to encode and decode NSCalendarUnit

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

How to encode and decode `NSCalendarUnit` like other objects, like

```
self.myStr = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myStr"];
[encoder encodeObject:self.myStr forKey:@"myStr"];
```

Tried to save `NSCalendarUnit` in `NSNumber` like this `@(self.repetition);` but I am getting `64` when I log.

I want to encode `NSCalendarUnit` and save it, later when required decode it and use it for comparison like this `if(xxxxx == NSCalendarUnit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSCalendarUnit` is an unsigned long, so it can be "boxed" (made into an object) using two methods on `NSNumber` intended for unsigned longs:

```
NSCalendarUnit someNSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnitDay;
NSNumber *boxed = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:someNSCalendarUnit];
```

and

```
NSCalendarUnit unboxed = [boxed unsignedLongLongValue];
// now, unboxed == someNSCalendarUnit
```

And you probably know how to encode an decode NSNumbers, just add the additional box-step to the encode/decode methods...

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];

    NSNumber *boxed = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:self.someNSCalendarUnit];
    [encoder encodeObject:boxed forKey:@"someNSCalendarUnit"];
    // ...

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSNumber *boxed = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someNSCalendarUnit"];
        _someNSCalendarUnit = [boxed unsignedLongLongValue];
        // ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`NSCalendarUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendarunit?language=objc) is an option set (`NS_OPTIONS`), which means a `NSCalendarUnit` value can be none, one, or more values of the units.
You'll need to do a [bit mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) `if ((xxxx & NSCalendarUnitHour) != 0)` to check for values.

You're fine encoding the value like you are now, as a `NSNumber` and using `NSNumber.unsignedInteger` to get the value when decoding (note that the enum for `NSCalendarUnit` is defined as a `NSUInteger`). (Note you can also store the value as a `NSInteger` using [`-[NSCoder encodeInteger:forKey:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder/1411551-encodeinteger?language=objc).)

**Serialisation**

```
[encoder encodeObject:@(self.repetition) forKey:@"repetition"];
```

**Deserialisation**

```
self.repetition = [[decoder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSNumber class] 
                   forKey:@"repetition"] unsignedInteger];
```

**Checking**

```
if ((self.repetition & NSCalendarUnitHour) != 0) {
    // Do something
} else if ((self.repetition & NSCalendarUnitMinute) != 0) {
    // Do something
}
```